# How to amplify an electret microphone

Tags: transistors, amplifier, microphone

I need to amplify an electret microphone for use with an Arduino Uno. I have a few capacitors and resistors and several transistors one of which is an N-channel.
Any ideas?
Can you please also provide me with a scheme?

Comment: I don't understand. We cannot use resistors, capacitors, other transistors, or ICs?

Comment: We also have resistors 10 kiloOhms and 220 Ohms

Comment: The Arduino Uno isn't a PIC! Question cannot be answered and should be closed.

Comment: Well it has one, which you can control and etc...

Comment: @LeonHeller: it seems that more and more people think PIC is another word for microcontroller. "The PIC is an Atmel AVR."

Comment: This is most easily done with a opamp.  It's not too hard to do it with a few transistors either, but some other components like a few resistors and capacitors will be needed either way.  Restricting the problem to what you happen to have on hand is silly because it's easy to get these other parts.

Comment: how much gain do you need? ![Amplifer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ftiR5.png)

Comment: @OlinLathrop - you are probably correct about availability, but being in Bulgaria may add a degree of hardness and the op's means may be restricted

Comment: Do you have access to whatever supplier for components?

Comment: @FedericoRusso - I've noticed that too.  However prevalent it may be, it's WRONG.

Comment: @Itehnological: Take a look at this product: http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8872. It's a mic preamp, and it says it supports electret mics. *Note that it doesn't come assembled, so you will need to buy the parts separately!* Some of the parts you can get right off of SparkFun, but I'd recommend mouser.com or digikey.com to save money. If you have most of the parts, and just want to make it a breadboard, then just take a look at the schematic instead.

Comment: I had a great answer. What happened here ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok this will be quick and hopefully painless.

[image: microphone amplifier]

I am not well versed in the microphones themselves, sometimes they are biased sometimes they are not.

So the way this is designed:

Remove DC bias from microphone output

Bias the transistor so that it can maximize the usable range

(For simplicity make R1= R2 10k resistors or less should do it)

Rg (plus the beta of the amplifier) control the gain of the circuit. The higher Rg the higher the gain. HOWEVER, the larger Rg gets the more power it dissipates. this is for low current systems.

the transistor is an NPN (always open, apply voltage to close)

This is also an INVERTING amplifier. For audio applications you will not hear the difference; however, if you use it for anything else it applies a negative gain.

(Vout= -Gain*vin)

Comment: That transistor looks like an IGBT...

Comment: you can use almost any transistor, but if you want the signal to remain linear with minimal harmonic distortion, i advise using an npn.

Comment: Yes, I already guessed it's supposed to be an NPN. You definitely don't want an IGBT for this! :-)

Comment: also i wrote above it was an NPN >_<;

Comment: No problem, I only meant to say that the [symbol](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/IGBT_structure_chart_3.PNG) you drew looks like having an insulated gate.

Comment: Where are the power inputs?  I see 4 connections to ground, but no current input.

Comment: you see that line on the top that connects R1 and RG, that is traditionally the power input. (i.e, power comes from the top and goes to the bottom)