# electret condenser microphone plugged directly into arduino

Tags: arduino

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a microphone with an Arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36795/using-a-microphone-with-an-arduino)

Can I plug electret condenser microphone directly in ardunio and read ambient sound level? I imagine those microphones pickup sound like voltage and change accordingly...

Will there be a need to amplify signal?
what if I plug in 5 microphones?
do I need to amplify each?

My project is very simply, I want to create 5 lights wich will activate based on sound level around them.

Comment: You cannot. Search google for "microphone preamp". Also, let's assume you microphone didn't provide an extremely small signal. That signal would still be AC. You have to offset it using a capacitor and a voltage divider. Recently someone asked what can happen to a microcontroller if you exceed the input range.

Comment: And yes, you have to amplify each. Don't worry though, the microphone preamplifier can be a simple circuit to make into a small pcb.

Comment: You don't even need to search google, as this question has been asked and answered many many times. Here's an [example](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/30774/11880).

Comment: to detect different sound levels , I think he need somekind of differential amplifier, where this was used in electrocardiography.

Comment: Not really a duplicate, this question is about using just an electrect microphone capsule (with no additional components), while the referenced question is about a more complex circuit (with amplification, etc.)